# Geojson multipolygon doesn't work with Leaflet bindPopup?

Tags: javascript, polygon, geojson, leaflet

I have polygon and multipolygon data in Geojson format and when I try to bind popup for polygon, it works perfectly, and when I try to bind it for multipolygon, it doesn't work.

Is that some Leaflet bug and how can I solve this?

Thanks

Comment: Can you post a live demo for us to examine? If not will you post the code?

Comment: https://github.com/againstflow/leafletmultipolygon

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It appears this is an open bug. See leaflet.js [issue 1319](https://github.com/Leaflet/Leaflet/issues/1319).

Comment: [This example](http://jsfiddle.net/MFuglsang/eaj6h/) seems to have multipolygons with popups. Maybe try reworking your code in this way.

Comment: I tried, but when I have if functions there's no way to succeed for more than 9 polygons.. It's a bug, obviously.